# Freeform Pro Show message when email is invalid

Tags: solspace-freeform

I'm using Freeform Pro composer to build a form. Validating with inline error messages.

Template code

```
{exp:freeform:composer
  form_name="contact_us"
  form_id="2" 
  composer_template_name="contact_us"
  return="contact_us/thank_you"
  inline_errors="yes"
  form:class="contact-us"
}
```

I have an email field that is required. The email Field Type is text and the Field Content Type is set to email.

If I submit the form without any data in the email field I get a message "Please fill in this field".

If I fill in the field with text that's not a valid email address, I would like it to display a message telling them a valid email address is required.

Is this something that can be done without any additional coding?

Thanks

Wayne.

Answer (score 0):

2 options, one is adding server side validation which will involve extending all sorts of internal's, the other which I feel you'd like is to use a HTML5 email type field (freeform uses a text field for the email import).

You can do this easily, please see this example that I am currently using on a site :

```
    {freeform:field:email 
        attr:type="email" 
        attr:id="email"
        attr:required="required"
        attr:size="36"
        attr:placeholder="Enter your email here..."}
    {if freeform:error:email}<p>{freeform:error:email}</p>{/if}
```

This produces the email field as so :

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Enter your email here..." size="36" required="required" maxlength="150" id="email" value="" name="email">
```

Note this is client side validation, HTML5 validation only! But the server side option can be alot more complex! the irony is that CodeIgnitor has a valid_email filter, it's just that Freeform doesn't seem to use it!

Comment: Thanks Blatant,
That seems to be what I need. I'm not sure how/where to add it to my Composer template.

Could you please let me know where to add it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with composer, but that syntax is [freeform field syntax](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/default_fieldtypes/) , if you look to the [composer documentation](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/composer/), right at the bottom it details how to add the "required" html5 attribute, you can use the same technique for the placeholder, type and other attributes detailed.